# Removing elements from one int list to another

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
// public means anyone can use it.
// Java ALWAYS looks for a "main" method to run.
public class incrementing {

    // Method
    // anything within a parameter is called an argument. Any extra information the method needs for it in order to work.
    void calc() {

        // Creating our array of 10 slots.
        int[] increments = new int [9];

        // Creating a "counter" to work with the array,
        int i = 0;

        // while loop to add elements to our slots.
        while (i < increments.length) {
            increments[i] = i;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(increments));

        // for loop implementation. 
        int[] newlist = new int[9];
        for (int e : increments) {
            newlist.add(increments[0]);
            newlist[e] = increments[e];
            e++;

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newlist));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(increments));
    }
    // Main performs the actual actions.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating an object of the class.
        // "test" allows me to use everything within the class of (calc).
        incrementing test = new incrementing();
        test.calc();
    }
}
```

How can I add all the element values from "increments" to "newlist"?

I'm originally from Python so I would've just popped and appended the values but honestly lost in Java to do this.

Comment: Do you have to use an `int[]` array? Using a `List` would allow for the interchange more easily.

Comment: An array is not a list, but you are expecting list-like features.

Answer (score 0):

There is no add method in arrays in java, modify your for loop like the following, you can copy from one array to the other using indices like this

```
    for (int e=0 ; i<  increments.length; e++) {
        newlist[e] = increments[e]; 
    }
```

comments on your for loop, `e` is not an index it is an element. you can not use add method in arrays.

```
  for (int e : increments) {
        newlist.add(increments[0]);
        newlist[e] = increments[e];
        e++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Apache Commons (org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils), you could use:

`newlist = ArrayUtils.addAll(newlist, increments)`

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
for (i = 0; i < increments.length; i++) { // where i is previously defined in the scope.
    newList[i] = increments[i];
}
```

What you should know here -> `i` is used as index for both the arrays and for arrays with equal length you have the guarantee that each index in `increments` will have a representing index in `newList`. If you try to access an index that is less than `0` and greater than `N - 1`(N is the size of the array), an IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown.

If you want to make an exact copy of an array in Java usually you would go for:

```
int[] newList1 = Arrays.copyOf(increments, increments.length);
```

You can find more info on the Arrays class at [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-)

Answer (score 0):

This for loop is basically for-each loop. So the **e** value in each iteration is a subsequent number from the **increment** list. So if you do: `increments =  {3,5,2};`
and you do:

```
for(int i: increments){
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

you will see on console: `3 5 2`

This is how it should look:

```
//double check to not get IndexOutofbounds of any of array
for (int i = 0; (i < newlist.length) && (i < increments.length); i++) { 
    newlist[i] = increments[i];
}
```

You can do it even faster:

```
newlist = increments.clone();
```

Btw. Notice that `new int [9];` allocate just only 9 "slots". And all your classes should start with a capital letter.

And take a look at the **List** class. They are a little similar to the python lists.